# Compute rotation matrices from arrays of "aim" and "up" vectors

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I want to compute an array of rotation matrices from given arrays of `aim` and `up` vectors.

For simplicity I'll assume the `aim` axes will correspond to the matrices's `x` components, and `up` axes to the matrices's `y` components.

The only way that i know of is by doing a series of cross products:

```
import cProfile
import numpy as np
from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d

normalize = lambda V: V/(inner1d(V,V)**0.5)[:,np.newaxis] # inner1d is faster than np.linalg.norm on large arrays

def vectorToMatrix(X,Y):
    X = normalize(X) # make sure X is normalized
    Z = normalize(np.cross(X,Y)) # Z is the normal to the XY plane

    # Re-adjust Y to keep matrices orthogonal
    Y = np.cross(Z,X)
    return np.dstack((X,Y,Z)).swapaxes(2,1)
```

Running this on a million random items

```
np.random.seed(30)
n = 10**6
X = np.random.random((n,3))
Y = np.random.random((n,3))
M = vectorToMatrix(X,Y)

cProfile.run('vectorToMatrix(X,Y)') # 61 function calls in 0.255 seconds
```

I'm looking for other methods, preferably leveraging `numpy/scipy`, that could help calculate the same result given by `vectorToMatrix` with a performance boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's my attempt with `@jit`

```
from numba import jit, float64 as float

@jit(float[:,:](float[:,:], float[:,:]), nopython=True)
def crossj(a, b):
    c = np.empty(a.shape)
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            c[i, j] = a[i, j-2] * b[i, j-1] - a[i, j-1] * b[i, j-2]
    return c
```

This is quite a bit faster than @Divakar

```
np.allclose(np.cross(X,Y), crossj(X,Y) )

True

%timeit np.cross(X,Y)
%timeit numpy_cross_slicing(X,Y)
%timeit crossj(X,Y)

10 loops, best of 3: 75.1 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 88.1 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 23 ms per loop
```

I'll swipe the `ne`-based `normalize` from @Divakar, and implement a seocnd `jit` for `normalize(np.cross())`

```
@jit(float[:,:](float[:,:], float[:,:]), nopython=True)
def norm_crossj(a, b):
    c = np.empty(a.shape)
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        n = 0
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            c[i, j] = a[i, j-2] * b[i, j-1] - a[i, j-1] * b[i, j-2]
            n += c[i,j]**2
        n = sqrt(n)
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            c[i,j] /= n
    return c
```

Once again, faster

```
%timeit normalize(np.cross(X,Y))
%timeit numpy_cross_norm_slicing(X,Y)
%timeit norm_crossj(X,Y)

10 loops, best of 3: 119 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 104 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 36.7 ms per loop
```

Finally:

```
def vectorToMatrixj(X, Y):
    normalize_einsum_numexpr(X) # make sure X is normalized
    #normalize_einsum_numexpr(Y) # you don't need this
    Z = norm_crossj(X, Y) # Z is the normal to the XY plane
    # Re-adjust Y to keep matrices orthogonal
    Y = crossj3(Z, X)
    return np.dstack((X,Y,Z)).swapaxes(2,1)
```

Not sure why @Divakar's timings seem to be so different, or why my speedups don't help more, but:

```
%timeit vectorToMatrix(X,Y)
%timeit vectorToMatrix1(X,Y) #Divakar
%timeit vectorToMatrix2(X,Y) #Divakar
%timeit vectorToMatrixj(X,Y)

1 loop, best of 3: 265 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 319 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 258 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 212 ms per loop
```

**EDIT:** fully `jit`ted function:

```
@jit(float[:,:,:](float[:,:], float[:,:]), nopython=True)
def vec2matj(a, b):
    c = np.empty(a.shape + a.shape[-1:])
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        na = 0
        nc = 0
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            c[i, 2, j] = a[i, j-2] * b[i, j-1] - a[i, j-1] * b[i, j-2]
            na += a[i, j]**2
            nc += c[i, 2, j]**2
        na = sqrt(na)
        nc = sqrt(nc)
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            c[i, 2, j] /= nc
            c[i, 0, j] = a[i, j] / na
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            c[i, 1, j] = c[i, 2, j-2] * c[i, 0, j-1] - c[i, 2, j-1] * c[i, 0, j-2]
    return c

np.allclose(vectorToMatrix(X,Y), vec2matj(X,Y))
True

%timeit vec2matj(X,Y)
%timeit vectorToMatrix(X,Y)

10 loops, best of 3: 60.8 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 240 ms per loop   # <- different computer than timings above
```

Comment: i'm not sure if this is a Python 3 vs 2.7 issue (i'm on 2.7) but to make your code work i had add `float64` to your imports and replace all `float[:,:]` to `float64[:,:]`

Comment: On my machine my solution, Divakar's and yours run at 223,172,120ms respectively. Almost twice as fast as my original. Also thanks for introducing me to numba!

Comment: Seems like `numba` is the trendy one!

Comment: Oops, forgot that import.  Fixed.

Comment: Also noticed that you don't actually need to normalize `Y`, as you're normalizing `Z` and replacing `Y` later.

Comment: Added fully `jit` function that does a 4x speedup.

Comment: @DanielF you opened up a whole world of possibilities by showing numba to me, so thanks again. Was looking some more into the package and saw that numba can use cuda to do some work on the GPU. Is this something that would apply here?

Comment: No idea.  I'm only about a week ahead of you at working my way through `numba`

Answer (score 1):

Three stages of marginal improvements are possible with tricks from `np.einsum` and `numexpr` module.

**Stage #1 :** Compute normalize outputs using `sum-reduction` with `einsum` and then leveraging `numexpr` for performing squared-roots -

```
import numexpr as ne

def normalize_einsum_numexpr(X):
    sq_sums = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',X,X)[:,None]
    return ne.evaluate('X/sqrt(sq_sums)')
```

This would be equivalent of `normalize(X)`.

**Stage #2 :** Get numpy.cross equivalent with slicing using the definition of `cross-product` -

```
def numpy_cross_slicing(X,Y):
    c0 = X[:,1]*Y[:,2] - X[:,2]*Y[:,1]
    c1 = X[:,2]*Y[:,0] - X[:,0]*Y[:,2]
    c2 = X[:,0]*Y[:,1] - X[:,1]*Y[:,0]
    return np.column_stack((c0,c1,c2))
```

**Stage #3 :** Get normalized cross product with slicing and also leveraging `numexpr` -

```
def numpy_cross_norm_slicing(X,Y):
    c0 = X[:,1]*Y[:,2] - X[:,2]*Y[:,1]
    c1 = X[:,2]*Y[:,0] - X[:,0]*Y[:,2]
    c2 = X[:,0]*Y[:,1] - X[:,1]*Y[:,0]

    s = ne.evaluate('sqrt(c0**2 + c1**2 + c2**2)')
    c0 /= s
    c1 /= s
    c2 /= s
    return np.column_stack((c0,c1,c2))
```

This would replace `normalize(np.cross(X,Y))`.

Putting it all together, we would have the replacement for `vectorToMatrix`, like so -

```
def vectorToMatrix1(X,Y):
    X = normalize_einsum_numexpr(X) # make sure X is normalized
    Y = normalize_einsum_numexpr(Y) # make sure Y is normalized
    Z = numpy_cross_norm_slicing(X,Y) # Z is the normal ...
    Y = numpy_cross_slicing(Z,X)
    return np.dstack((X,Y,Z)).swapaxes(2,1)
```

**Runtime test**

Input setup :

```
In [271]: X = np.random.random((10**6,3))
     ...: Y = np.random.random((10**6,3))
     ...:
```

Stage #1 :

```
In [272]: np.allclose(normalize(X), normalize_einsum_numexpr(X))
Out[272]: True

In [273]: %timeit normalize(X)
     ...: %timeit normalize_einsum_numexpr(X)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 11.4 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 10.6 ms per loop
```

Stage #2 :

```
In [274]: np.allclose(np.cross(X,Y), numpy_cross_slicing(X,Y) )
Out[274]: True

In [275]: %timeit np.cross(X,Y)
     ...: %timeit numpy_cross_slicing(X,Y)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 29.8 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 27.9 ms per loop
```

Stage #3 :

```
In [276]: np.allclose(normalize(np.cross(X,Y)), numpy_cross_norm_slicing(X,Y))
Out[276]: True

In [277]: %timeit normalize(np.cross(X,Y))
     ...: %timeit numpy_cross_norm_slicing(X,Y)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 44.5 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 34.9 ms per loop
```

Entire code :

```
In [395]: np.allclose(vectorToMatrix(X,Y), vectorToMatrix1(X,Y))
Out[395]: True

In [396]: %timeit vectorToMatrix(X,Y)
10 loops, best of 3: 130 ms per loop

In [397]: %timeit vectorToMatrix1(X,Y)
10 loops, best of 3: 122 ms per loop
```

Hence, some marginal improvement only.

---

**Not giving up!**

Looking into the bottlenecks, the many stacking steps weren't helping. So, improving on those, a modified version ended up like this -

```
def vectorToMatrix2(X,Y):
    X = normalize_einsum_numexpr(X) # make sure X is normalized
    Y = normalize_einsum_numexpr(Y) # make sure Y is normalized

    c0 = X[:,1]*Y[:,2] - X[:,2]*Y[:,1]
    c1 = X[:,2]*Y[:,0] - X[:,0]*Y[:,2]
    c2 = X[:,0]*Y[:,1] - X[:,1]*Y[:,0]

    s = ne.evaluate('sqrt(c0**2 + c1**2 + c2**2)')
    c0 /= s
    c1 /= s
    c2 /= s

    d0 = c1*X[:,2] - c2*X[:,1]
    d1 = c2*X[:,0] - c0*X[:,2]
    d2 = c0*X[:,1] - c1*X[:,0]

    c = [c0,c1,c2]
    d = [d0,d1,d2]
    return np.concatenate((X.T, d, c)).reshape(3,3,-1).transpose(2,0,1)
```

New timings with same million points setup -

```
In [505]: %timeit vectorToMatrix(X,Y) # original code
     ...: %timeit vectorToMatrix1(X,Y)
     ...: %timeit vectorToMatrix2(X,Y)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 130 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 117 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 101 ms per loop
```

`20%+` speedup, not too bad!

Comment: Thanks so much! I had completely forgotten about numexpr!.